# mysql update qty on complete order array

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to update quantities left in stock on all items in the order, when the order is completed in a point of sale system

my code so far is

```
$order=$_GET["order"];

include('php/config.php');


$invoice=$order;
$voucher=$_GET['voucher'];
$card=$_GET['card'];
$cash=$_GET["cash"];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$sql="SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE  `invoice` = '".$invoice."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$parts[] = array(
"part" => $row['part'], 
"qty" => $row['qty'], 
 );

$sqlstock = "UPDATE `stock` SET available='available - $parts[qty]' WHERE 

part = '".$parts['part']."'";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best to do this as a single piece of SQL:-

```
UPDATE stock a INNER JOIN order b ON a.part = b.part 
SET a.available = a.available - b.qty
WHERE  b.invoice` = '$order'
```

Watch out that you don't just rerun this multiple times without some way of checking that an order hasn't already been used to update the stock

Doing it this way, if you had 1000 items on the order then it is a single query. Doing a select and then looping around the results would require 10001 queries.

Comment: ` $sqlstock = mysql_query("UPDATE stock b, orders p 
   SET b.available = b.available- p.qty
 WHERE b.part = p.part
   AND p.invoice = '".$invoice."'");
`

Comment: Pretty much the same. You have just used the older way of doing a join, and used $invoice variable (in your script you have just set $invoice to equal $order). Note you should check that $invoice / $order is safe (ie, if a string run it through mysql_real_escape_string and if an integers use intval).

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop to this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $parts[] = array(
    "part" => $row['part'], 
    "qty" => $row['qty'], 
     );

    $sqlstock = mysql_query("UPDATE `stock` SET available=available - $parts[qty] WHERE part = 
    '".$part['part']."'");
}
```

Comment: i Dont know what i'm doing wrong but still can't get this to work, it doesnt through up any errors but wont update quantities

Comment: The code is setting up a piece of SQL to do the update, but it also needs to actually execute that SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problems are with `available='available - $parts[qty]'` and `.$parts.`

The `available='available - $parts[qty]'` will be interpreted as a string so change it to

`available=available - {$parts['qty']}`

and change `.$parts.` to `.$parts['part']`

Also if you are writing this as new code consider converting your `mysql_` functions to `mysqli_` or use PDO as mysl is now deprecated and no longer supported in PHP.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php